# How to map a dataframe with a list column (to be mapped) and an id in R

Tags: r, list, dictionary

I want to do a map in a list inside a data.frame, bind the rows and repeat a column ID in one step.

I was able to do doing each part manually, but wasn't able to do in one step process, if there is any function or a specific way to use the mapping functions.

Data header:

```
data <- structure(list(mecanicas = list(structure(list(name = c("Campaign / Battle Card Driven", 
"Cooperative Play", "Grid Movement", "Hand Management", "Modular Board", 
"Role Playing"), objecttype = c("property", "property", "property", 
"property", "property", "property"), objectid = c("2018", "2023", 
"2676", "2040", "2011", "2028"), primarylink = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), itemstate = c("approved", "approved", "approved", 
"approved", "approved", "approved"), href = c("/boardgamemechanic/2018/campaign-battle-card-driven", 
"/boardgamemechanic/2023/cooperative-play", "/boardgamemechanic/2676/grid-movement", 
"/boardgamemechanic/2040/hand-management", "/boardgamemechanic/2011/modular-board", 
"/boardgamemechanic/2028/role-playing")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L)), structure(list(name = c("Action Point Allowance System", 
"Cooperative Play", "Hand Management", "Point to Point Movement", 
"Set Collection", "Trading"), objecttype = c("property", "property", 
"property", "property", "property", "property"), objectid = c("2001", 
"2023", "2040", "2078", "2004", "2008"), primarylink = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), itemstate = c("approved", "approved", "approved", 
"approved", "approved", "approved"), href = c("/boardgamemechanic/2001/action-point-allowance-system", 
"/boardgamemechanic/2023/cooperative-play", "/boardgamemechanic/2040/hand-management", 
"/boardgamemechanic/2078/point-point-movement", "/boardgamemechanic/2004/set-collection", 
"/boardgamemechanic/2008/trading")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
6L)), structure(list(name = c("Action Point Allowance System", 
"Auction/Bidding", "Card Drafting"), objecttype = c("property", 
"property", "property"), objectid = c("2001", "2012", "2041"), 
    primarylink = c(0L, 0L, 0L), itemstate = c("approved", "approved", 
    "approved"), href = c("/boardgamemechanic/2001/action-point-allowance-system", 
    "/boardgamemechanic/2012/auctionbidding", "/boardgamemechanic/2041/card-drafting"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), list()), 
    title = c("Gloomhaven", "Pandemic Legacy: Season 1", "Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization", 
    "KLASK")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Structure:

```
  mecanicas            title                                        
  <list>               <chr>                                        
1 <data.frame [6 x 6]> Gloomhaven                                   
2 <data.frame [6 x 6]> Pandemic Legacy: Season 1                    
3 <data.frame [3 x 6]> Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization
4 <list [0]>           KLASK
```

The way I do it and want to simplify:

```
library('tidyverse')

### map and bind the rows
mechanics_binded <- map_dfr(data$mecanicas, bind_rows) 

### then count the mechanics for repetition
n_mecs <- lapply(data[['mecanicas']], nrow) %>% as.character() %>% as.numeric()

##(some lists can be empty, but none in the data sample)
n_mecs[is.na(n_mecs)] <- 0 


titles <- rep(data$title, n_mecs)

mechanics_binded$titles <- titles 

mechanics <- mechanics_binded [,c('name', 'jogos')]

mechanics
```

Desired result:

```
                            name                     title
1  Campaign / Battle Card Driven                Gloomhaven
2               Cooperative Play                Gloomhaven
3                  Grid Movement                Gloomhaven
4                Hand Management                Gloomhaven
5                  Modular Board                Gloomhaven
6                   Role Playing                Gloomhaven
7  Action Point Allowance System Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
8               Cooperative Play Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
9                Hand Management Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
10       Point to Point Movement Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
```

EDIT: The `mecanicas` column can be an empty list as well, otherwiser it's well structured.

EDIT2: added one of the edge case from edit1 that a list is empty (error in tidyverse solution case). The other error (data.table solution) I was unable to reproduce without the whole data, so I'm sharing here through dropbox link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/boh8k0epay4gedh/bgg_mechanics.RData?dl=0

Comment: Right now there are 3 answers posted, all of which you've said would work except for a null case that's not included in your sample. To get a more robust solution, you'll need to provide a sample where these additional issues occur

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to reproduce all errors without the need to upload all data. Just included one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `data` consists of

- a list `mecanicas` of data frames with identical structure (number, name, and type of columns) and
- a character vector `title` with the same number of elements as there are data frames in `mecanicas`

An alternative approach is to use `rbindlist()` to "flatten" the data structure, i.e., combine the pieces into one large data frame.

```
library(data.table)
# combine pieces to large data frame, add id col
flat <- rbindlist(data$mecanicas, idcol = "title")
# replace number in id col by title from character vector
flat[, title := data$title[title]][]
# extract desired columns
flat[, .(name, title)]
```

> ```
>                              name                                         title
>  1: Campaign / Battle Card Driven                                    Gloomhaven
>  2:              Cooperative Play                                    Gloomhaven
>  3:                 Grid Movement                                    Gloomhaven
>  4:               Hand Management                                    Gloomhaven
>  5:                 Modular Board                                    Gloomhaven
>  6:                  Role Playing                                    Gloomhaven
>  7: Action Point Allowance System                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
>  8:              Cooperative Play                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
>  9:               Hand Management                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
> 10:       Point to Point Movement                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
> 11:                Set Collection                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
> 12:                       Trading                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1
> 13: Action Point Allowance System Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization
> 14:               Auction/Bidding Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization
> 15:                 Card Drafting Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization
> ```

As the OP has reported some errors with the production dataset, here are a few checks to verify above assumptions hold:

```
library(magrittr)
# check that number of columns of data frames is consistent
stopifnot(lengths(data$mecanicas) %>% all(.[1] == .))
# or, without piping:
(tmp <- lengths(data$mecanicas))
stopifnot(all(tmp[1] == tmp))
# check that number of data frames and titles is consistent
stopifnot(length(data$mecanicas) == length(data$title))
```

Comment: Sorry, the `mecanicas` can be an empty list as well. If it's not empty it's as expected.

Comment: This case is not reflected in your sample dataset. What does `title` show in case of an empty list element in `mecanicas`?

Comment: It has a title, as others, nothings special.

Comment: Anyway, your method works flawlessly, without the `magrittr` part. Can't spot why though

Answer (score 2):

You want `tidyr::unnest`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  unnest(mecanicas) %>% 
  select(name, title)
```

Comment: Got the same problem as above, it does work on the sample data but when I go to the full one I receive `Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [mecanicas]` any idea what could it be?

Comment: Ok, I found that it's because of the empty lists (not the same reason when using DT), any idea of workaround? I'm looking through it, I'll post when I find something

Comment: This error means that some of the elements of your list column `mecanicas` are not dataframes (they are empty lists). One solution would be to explicitly cast all elements of `mecanicas` as data frames: add the line `mutate(mecanicas = mecanicas %>% map(data.frame)) ` in the pipe before the call to `unnest`.

Comment: Worked great adding that, also added the empty list on the sample data. Just looks to be a little computing heavy though.

Answer (score 2):

With data table you can `lapply` over `mecanicas` by `title`, and it will repeat the title for you.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)

data[, lapply(mecanicas, `[[`, 'name'), by = title]

#                                             title                            V1
#  1:                                    Gloomhaven Campaign / Battle Card Driven
#  2:                                    Gloomhaven              Cooperative Play
#  3:                                    Gloomhaven                 Grid Movement
#  4:                                    Gloomhaven               Hand Management
#  5:                                    Gloomhaven                 Modular Board
#  6:                                    Gloomhaven                  Role Playing
#  7:                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1 Action Point Allowance System
#  8:                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1              Cooperative Play
#  9:                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1               Hand Management
# 10:                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1       Point to Point Movement
# 11:                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1                Set Collection
# 12:                     Pandemic Legacy: Season 1                       Trading
# 13: Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization Action Point Allowance System
# 14: Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization               Auction/Bidding
# 15: Through the Ages: A New Story of Civilization                 Card Drafting
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've expected but there's something weird going on. It works on the sample data, but when I go to the full one I get the following error:
`Error in `[.data.table`(data, , lapply(mecanicas, `[[`, "name"), by = title) : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group`
Any idea what could It be?

Comment: Well, i see that between rows 1 and 442 it works fine, the 443 adds the error, but if I run the row 443 alone or with a couple more after it it runs fine. I've also checked the output as you've suggested doesn't seem to have anything abnormal. I'll check further and then I reply back.